# Prove: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are consecutive integers such that $a< b < c $ then $a^3 + b^3 \neq c^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> **Prove:** If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are consecutive integers such that $a<  b <  c $ then $a^3 + b^3  \neq  c^3$.

**My Attempt:** I start with direct proof.

Let $a,b,c$ be consecutive integers and  $a<  b <  c $, there exists a integer $k$ such that $a=k, b=k+1, c=k+2$. Then $a^3+b^3=k^3+(k+1)^3=k^3+(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)$ and $c^3=(k+2)^3=k^3+6k^2+12k+8=(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)+(3k^2+9k+7)$. Hence, we have $k^3+(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)\neq (k^3+3k^2+3k+1)+(3k^2+9k+7)$ which implies $a^3+b^3\neq c^3$.

Does my proof valid ? And, is use Contradiction easier? If not, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: That seems fine to me.

Comment: Your left side should have $2k^3$ on it, so you need to argue that there is no $k$ that makes $-k^3+3k^2+9k+7=0$

Comment: I don't think the final line of implication can be so intuitively spotted, unless you can prove that there exists no integer $k$ such that $k^3 - 3k^2 -9k - 7 = 0$.

Comment: When in doubt, you could use the sledgehammer and quote the Wiles proof :)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:If $k^3 = 3k^2+9k+7 \to k(k^2-3k-9) = 7 \to k\mid 7 \to k = \pm 1, \pm 7$. Can you continue?

Comment: if $k=\pm 1 , \pm 7$, these will give me contradiction since this is a fall all proof, and I need to start with using contradiction, correct?

Comment: Yes, you do. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

$(k-1)^3+k^3=(k+1)^3\\\implies k^3=(k+1)^3-(k-1)^3\\\implies k^3=(k+1-k+1)(k^2+2k+1+k^2-1+k^2-2k+1)\\\implies k^3=2(3k^2+2)$

Let $p$ be a prime that divides $k$.

If $p$ be odd then $k^3=2(3k^2+2)\implies p\mid3k^2+2\implies p\mid 2$

Hence $k$ can't have an odd prime divisor. Therefore $k=2^t$. $(?)$

Now assume that $t>0\implies t\ge 1$

Then we have,

$2^{3t}=2(3\cdot2^{2t}+2)\implies 2^{3t-1}=3\cdot 2^{2t}+2\implies2^{3t-2}=3\cdot 2^{2t-1}+1\implies t=\dfrac{1}{2}\ (?)$

Which implies $t=0$. But putting $t=0$ the equation is not satisfied. Hence the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove one more thing: $k^3\neq3k^2+9k+7$. Since the equation $k^3-3k^2-9k-7=0$ has no integer solutions, the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose$$(k-1)^3+k^3=(k+1)^3$$ $$2k^3-3k^2+3k-1=k^3+3k^2+3k+1$$ $$k^3-6k^2-2=0$$ $$k^2(k-6)=2 ,\,\,\,\,\text{where $k$ is an integer. }$$

Comment: Since $2$ is a prime $k^2$ or $k-6$ should be $1.$